# Send Pickled data to graphite

Tags: python, pickle, graphite

I am in a situation where I am generating multiple text files with thousands of metrics and I want to send them as [pickled data](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html#the-pickle-protocol) to graphite instead of looping line by line to save time. I am not familiar with python so if any one has an example of how the script should look like to do so. I am flexible with the text file format and I can generate it to suit the required format by python and graphite.
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

```
from carbon_client import CarbonClient

carbon = CarbonClient('localhost', 2004)

pickle = []

# loop through lines and add the metrics to pickle

pickle.append((name, (time, result)))


carbon.send_pickle(pickle)
```

Note that dont go too big with the pickle http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html#the-plaintext-protocol

If you count the size of the metrics that you are putting into the pickle, you can send the pickle when it reaches a certain size

```
limit = 10 * 1024
            if size >= limit:
                carbon.send_pickle(pickle)
                size = 0
                pickle = []
```